# Absolute value of a generator of the different

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraic function field over $\mathbb F_q$, in other words $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb F_q(t)=F$; furthermore fix a valuation $v$ on $K$.

Consider the [relative different ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Different_ideal) $\mathfrak D_v$  with respect to $K|F$. It tourns out that $\mathfrak D$ is a principal ideal of the valuation ring $\mathcal O_v$, so suppose that $\mathfrak D=d\mathcal O_v$.
I would like to know a way to calculate $|d|_v$ where $|\cdot|_v$ is the  absolute value associated to $v$.

Many sources (mainly texts on Tate's thesis) claim that $|d_v|=\frac{1}{\#(\mathcal O_v/\mathfrak D_v)}$, but I don't understand why this is true. Also it is not clear why $\#(\mathcal O_v/\mathfrak D_v)$ is finite.